# Can't find libgfortran-3.dll in Fortran

Tags: dll, fortran, gfortran, mingw32, fortran95

I am new to mingw32-gfortran, and I am finding it hard to statically link the specific dll's. I am trying to write a code on finding large factorials,the code compiles without any errors on code::blocks but gives an error about missing dll's when opened from cmd. Is there anyway to statically link these dll's to my exe (I don't mind if it is bloated,I just want my code to be portable).

Does gfortran provide similar libraries for static linking? I have also posted my code for any reference. It would really mean much to me if someone here helped me out, I have already tried code blocks forums,and read numerous posts on other websites. Still no luck.

Note : I use Win 7 64-bit

```
! A fortran95 program for G95
! By WQY
program main
implicit none
integer ,allocatable,dimension (:) :: a
integer :: re_i,n,digit=1,temp=0,zero=0,i,j,beg,rate,ends
allocate(a(10000000))
a(1)=1
print*,'please enter the number'
read *, n
call system_clock(beg,rate)
do j=2,n
do i=zero+1,digit
temp=temp+a(i)*j
a(i)=temp-(temp/10)*10
temp=temp/10
end do
do while (temp>0)
digit=digit+1
a(digit) = temp-(temp/10)*10
temp = (temp/10)
end do

do while(a(zero+1)==0)
        zero=zero+1
end do
end do
call system_clock(ends,rate)
write(*,1,advance='no') a(digit)
write (*,2,advance ='no') '.'

write (*,1) ( a(i),i=digit-1,digit-50,-1)
1   format(120i1)


print *,' X 10^' ,digit-1
2 format(100a1)

print '("computation time ",f6.3," seconds")',real(ends-beg)/real(rate)


re_i=system("pause")
end
```

Does anyone know how to compile a program in gfortan from command line? Errors seems to pop up every time I try to do so.

Comment: I tried adding an image ,but they wont let me because i'm new .Sry

Comment: You could just put `libgfortran-3.dll` in the same directory, should work. That's portable enough isn't it?

Comment: Yes I could but then I might loose portability because all my user wouldn't generally know how important the dll's are.

Comment: Look around in the `mingw32-gfortran` folder for any `.lib` files. If you find one that looks like the static equivalent of `libgfortran-3.dll` then you could try linking against that.

Comment: Hey sry for the late reply,had trouble with exams. Itried but there seems to be none.Thanks anyway

Comment: Has anyone tried out these dll to lib converters.